# Small image resizing for big! Alternative to timthumb

Tags: images

I come here to ask for help for you ! I need some script in PHP or some explanation to take my picture posted on highlighted images and resize to the size I need?

I know and add_image_size do this , but when a small image and it does not resize to a higher standard!

Eg image 200px wide be resized ( even losing quality ) to 600px wide! The timthumb do it , the more it you security problems and do not want to use it ! Does anyone have any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're always blowing up a small image to a larger size, and don't care about the resulting loss in quality (although personally I would, for photos at least) then you might as well simply override the height and width in CSS (or inline HTML) - there's no gain in making the image file on your server any bigger.

And yes, don't ever use [TimThumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2014/09/timthumb-end-life/).

Comment: and as you would in CSS and HTML as already tried a max- width: 100 % and the picture is not 100 % width .

Comment: Use `width: 100%` instead of `max-width: 100%` and make sure the parent DIV or container have a fix width & height